# how can I tell if a lucene segment is not current and not open by any index reader?

Tags: azure, lucene, lucene.net

I am using AzureDirectory to update a local SimpleFSDirectory from a blob storage. This update process runs on an Azure WebJob.

It works, but the local lucene directory gets crowded with old segment files.

Some of the old segment files might be still in use by cached Index Readers.

How can I know if the segment file is not part of the current segments and is not in use anymore (by any reader)?

Thanks!